# Where in Burlington, VT can I store luggage?

Tags: luggage-storage, vermont

Are there any publicly accessible lockers or left luggage facilities in Burlington VT where I could leave a bag while exploring the town on foot?

Seems like there could be something at the University of Vermont, but I can't find info.

Comment: There are [luggage storage apps](https://travelislife.org/best-luggage-storage-apps/) that connect you with local businesses that will store bags for a fee.  Bounce shows five locations in and around Burlington, looks like they are UPS Store locations.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your bag size, the [YMCA in Burlington](http://www.gbymca.org/membership/rates-and-payment/) has a daily guest rate of $12. They also have an active bike "campaign" with [bike lockers](http://www.burlingtonwalkbike.org/faq) that cost $0.25 per use (although there are only 5).

[image]

Comment: Good research! 

Answer (score 2):

The Hilton Garden Inn in Downtown Burlington let us store our bags free of charge all day. I had first asked the YMCA, which did not allow it (even for a fee).

Answer (score 1):

Bizarrely, the [train station](https://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer?pagename=am/am2Station/Station_Page&code=ESX), [airport](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/burlington.htm) and other places in Burlington, VT appear to have no luggage storage areas.

The University Of Vermont only provides such facilities for students.

You could try to get a hotel to take the luggage for a few hours for a small charge when you get there, as they have luggage stores. Otherwise, I am not aware of any facilities that could help with what you are looking for.

Comment: The "Burlington" train station isn't particularly close to downtown Burlington anyhow — it's about 8 miles away in neighboring Essex Junction.

Comment: Okay. The exact location wasn't posted in the question